# Get downloads & file browsing requests from HTMLFrame

Tags: actionscript-3

I am able to load and display files using the HTMLLoader class. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html

Problem is, when a user navigates to a download link or an upload button, nothing happens. I heard somewhere that any downloads get sent over to the user's main document folder. Anyway to intercept this and get some details? Someone in my browsing history suggested to somehow get it using the Socket class to fetch it's data and control where it would go using the File class. I couldn't make out the demonstration.

Bonus question...what properties do I have to set to make Google understand that this browser is not a bot? I get this in plain text when trying to navgiate to http://www.google.com . It's other services work completely fine though.

> Google
> Sorry...
>
> We're sorry...
>
> ... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

Comment: Have you looked at using the StageWebView class (with useNative=true) vs. HTMLLoader,  StageWebView(useNative:Boolean = false). HTMLLoader is based on a really, really, really old version of WebKit.

Comment: The Google response is seen usually when you are using a VPN that has been gray listed or an IP address/block that has be used to crawl google for search results.

Comment: I played around with StageWebView, but it says it can't act as a display object and I'm wanting to do other things to the display (such as overlap with other objects, dim, tween, and position it easily by putting it in a movieclip) though if it is based on an older version..I might have to go through the difficulties on working with it :/

Comment: Ya, if you are trying to use it like a display object that is a no go... What I did was use the StageWebView.drawViewPortToBitmapData and use that bitmap in a display object, but I did not have any animations running within the web view. I also could fly the bitmap in as a texture using Stage3D, swap it with the stagewebview, allow the user to interact with the web page, grab a new bitmap of the view, hide the web view while flying the new bitmap out. Also work really well as doing a 'web page' carousel' like that....

Comment: That's actually very clever. Thing is, if I come across a Youtube video (or any animation) that method might be a little process intensive..

However, that might work as far as inactivity goes. The animations only occur when the user "tabs out" to look at other tabs and browses for active ones. I could just store and animate a bunch of bitmaps...keep the StageWebView in the center..>> if I put all of that inside an swf, could I load that swf onto the stage, and have movieclips from my main swf display objects over that? If the user get's a call, a movieclip is suppose to animate in with a tab.

Comment: Not sure about as the web view is alway on top of Flash content, I placed the bitmap capture 'under' web view and removed the web view from the stage... i.e. : From Adobe's blog: it’s not possible to position Flash content on top of a StageWebView (Flash content is always drawn below), taking a snapshot of the content lets developers swap the StageWebView out for a bitmap when you need to position Flash content on top of it, then swap the StageWebView back when you’re ready.

Comment: Man :/
The downside with that is when the user get's a call, its suppose to appear as an active tab on the side of the screen. So then the user can't browse the internet while having a call tab on display. There's workarounds (like resizing) but I wish there was another way.

Comment: Still unaware of how to handle downloads & uploads.